# Wi-Fi Adapter to use for 5GHz hostapd?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hostapd

I am currently trying to use `hostapd` to create a 5GHz Wi-Fi network. I have tried using the adapter mentioned in [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=80299) from Newegg, but I had the problem referenced in the post (I have become convinced it is a problem with the adapter).

I am now looking for a replacement adapter but don't want to buy something that is not going to work again. The only requirements are that it work on both the 2.4 and 5 GHz ranges and have a removable antenna (part of the project involves boosting the signal).

I am currently looking at [this Wi-Fi adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320175). Does anyone know if this adapter or chipset (RTL8812au) will work using `hostapd` in the 5GHz band? And does anyone have a recommendation for a Wi-Fi adapter that meets these specifications?

Answer (score 4):

It's not the card, it's the configuration.

From your `hostapd.conf`:

> hw_mode=g

802.11g is OFDM signaling up to 54Mbps ***in 2.4GHz specifically***. It's the 2.4GHz version of 802.11a, which did the same thing in 5GHz.

> channel=40

Wi-Fi channel 40 is a 5GHz channel. Its center frequency is 5.200 GHz. You cannot do 802.11g in 5GHz. If you want to do 802.11g-like signaling in 5GHz, it's called 802.11a. (Sorry for repeating myself.)

Your software even tried to tell you that in the error message:

> wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (40) not found from the channel list of current mode (1) IEEE 802.11g

**If you still decide you want to buy a new adapter:**
In my experience, the Wi-Fi chipmaker with historically the most vibrant open source community is Atheros (now "Qualcomm Atheros" or "QCA"). So look for adapters that use Atheros chips. You might want to use [WikiDevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Main_Page) to help you look up which adapters use which chipsets.